# select data from a table for only null

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to select only that data for which US data is not null and for other country it is null.

```
field1   field2    field3
A        US        A
A        DE        null
A        IN        null
A        JP        null
B        US        null
B        DE        B
B        IN        C
B        JP        null
```

Comment: please provide clear information what is your table name what are your columns names what conditions you want on it..

Comment: Can you show the layout of the table ?

Comment: I take it that "I need to select only that **data** for which US **data** is not null..." means "I need to select only those **field1** for which US record's **field3** is not null...". Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select field1 from 
(
select field1,
        field2,
        count(*) over (partition by field1) not_null_count
        from tablename
        where field3 is not null
        ) 
where field2 = 'US' 
and not_null_count = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

The query should be remarkably close to the requirements:

```
select *
from TableName
where (field2='US' and field3 is not null) or 
      (field2<>'US' and field3 is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just to properly use the **parenthesis** in the **predicate**:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  table_name
WHERE (field2 =  'US'  AND field3 IS NOT NULL)
OR    (field2 <> 'US'  AND field3 IS NULL)
```

Comment: this query won't select any rows because how field2 can be us and not us in the same time ?

Comment: ( a & b ) & ( c & d ) = ( a & c ) & ( b & d )

Comment: @robert It was a silly typo, I meant `OR` not `AND`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query

```
Select * from table_name where field2="US" && field3 IS NOT NULL OR field2!="US" && field3 IS NULL;
```

Comment: No I dont think this will return the data which I need to extract as it should be null for all other countries except for US.

Comment: It will return since for all others field2 ! (not) US is used in the second statement.